# Apparently wrong working directory in yml file

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions, continuous-deployment

Hey I'm currently working on a Github Actions workflow that automatically deploys my Hugo Website to my server. In the step of building the website

```
- name: build Hugo website
  run: |
    pwd
    ls -l
    hugo
  working-directory: Website/jasminsweets_ws
```

I get this error that its not the right path to my  directory where the files of the website are in:

```
Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/webshop-jasmin/webshop-jasmin/Website/jasminsweets_ws'. No such file or directory
```

I tried a lot of things like using different paths but it still won't fix the error. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

My repository: https://github.com/Team-Webshop-Jasmin/webshop-jasmin (the files of the website are in Website/jasminsweets_ws)

Comment: Can you please show the output from `pwd` and `ls` as well? (also, your formatting seems a bit off)

Comment: And I'm assuming there's a preceding checkout step?

Comment: `pwd` output: `/home/ubuntu` , `ls -l` output: `total 0`.  My teacher helped me with yml file. So he told me what I should include, theres no preceding checkout step

Comment: Then that's your problem :) You first need to check out your code

Comment: it finally works now thank you so much :) Don't know how my teacher didnt now notice that